# Removing only the leading zero and not all zeros

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, trim

the goal is to take the numbers in between 2 dashes and I was able to do that but the issue is that I need to remove the leading zero to the returned value.  How can I incorporate the LTRIM function or other functions without removing all zeros?

Sample:

```
123-010-456
```

Results should be 10

```
SELECT[Phone],
REPLACE(SUBSTRING([Phone], CHARINDEX('-', [Phone]), CHARINDEX('-', [Phone])),'-','') AS substring
FROM [SalesLT].[Customer]
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps MS SQL Server?)

Comment: Might be better asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What's the expected result if there are 3 dashes, or only 1? Add more diverse sample data to make the problem clearer.

Comment: I apologize, I am brand new to SQL world.  I am using MS SQL Server

Comment: No problem, we are all here to learn.

Comment: @jarlh there are only 2 dashes and I just need to get the number in between those 2 dashes without the leading zero.

Comment: @jarlh: samples 1-2-3 returns with 2,  001-002-003 returns with 2, 123-1111-56632 returns with 1111, 01234-1-629494 returns with 1... and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If your data pattern/format is fixed then below will help

```
SELECT RIGHT(PARSENAME(REPLACE('123-010-456','-','.'),2),2)
```

Comment: It's actually different formats and length but the key is looking for the 2 dashes.  I tried your query and it came back with all 10's for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the following to one query, but for better understanding I break it down to 3 steps.

```
DECLARE @String nvarchar(20) = '123-010-456'
DECLARE @MiddlePart nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @FirstNonZero int

--Get the middle part
SET @MiddlePart = SUBSTRING(@String,
                 CHARINDEX('-',@String)+1, --Find the 1st dash
                 LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX('-',@String)-CHARINDEX('-',Reverse(@String)) --Find length between two dashes
                 ) 

--Get the First Non zero number
SET @FirstNonZero = (SELECT MIN(x) 
                     FROM (SELECT CHARINDEX('1',@MiddlePart) as x WHERE CHARINDEX('1',@MiddlePart)>0 
                           UNION
                           SELECT CHARINDEX('2',@MiddlePart) as x WHERE CHARINDEX('2',@MiddlePart)>0 
                           UNION
                           SELECT CHARINDEX('3',@MiddlePart) as x WHERE CHARINDEX('3',@MiddlePart)>0 
                           UNION
                           SELECT CHARINDEX('4',@MiddlePart) as x WHERE CHARINDEX('4',@MiddlePart)>0 
                           UNION
                           SELECT CHARINDEX('5',@MiddlePart) as x WHERE CHARINDEX('5',@MiddlePart)>0 
                           UNION
                           SELECT CHARINDEX('6',@MiddlePart) as x WHERE CHARINDEX('6',@MiddlePart)>0 
                           UNION
                           SELECT CHARINDEX('7',@MiddlePart) as x WHERE CHARINDEX('7',@MiddlePart)>0 
                           UNION
                           SELECT CHARINDEX('8',@MiddlePart) as x WHERE CHARINDEX('8',@MiddlePart)>0 
                           UNION
                           SELECT CHARINDEX('9',@MiddlePart) as x WHERE CHARINDEX('9',@MiddlePart)>0 
                     ) a)

--Final
Select SUBSTRING(@MiddlePart,@FirstNonZero,LEN(@MiddlePart)-@FirstNonZero+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to extract the middle part and convert it to int - this will remove all leading zeroes while keeping the trailing ones... if required, you can then convert it back to varchar. Following an example:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(testval nvarchar(40))

INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('123-010-456')
,('1234-1-456789')
,('12-00010-4')
,('1-0007-4')

SELECT *
      ,SUBSTRING(testval, CHARINDEX('-', testval)+1, CHARINDEX('-', testval, CHARINDEX('-', testval)+1)-CHARINDEX('-', testval)-1)
      ,CAST(SUBSTRING(testval, CHARINDEX('-', testval)+1, CHARINDEX('-', testval, CHARINDEX('-', testval)+1)-CHARINDEX('-', testval)-1) AS INT)
  FROM @t
```